# How to convert many files from doc to docx with multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, file-io, parallel.foreach

I have millions of doc files which need to be converted to docx. I am currently using the below method to convert each file in the specified directory. How can I effectively multithread this process?

```
static void ConvertDocToDocx(string path)
{
    Application word = new Application();

    var sourceFile = new FileInfo(path);
    var document = word.Documents.Open(sourceFile.FullName);

    string newFileName = sourceFile.FullName.Replace(".doc", ".docx");
    document.SaveAs2(newFileName, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument,
                     CompatibilityMode: WdCompatibilityMode.wdWord2010);

    word.ActiveDocument.Close();
    word.Quit();

    //File.Delete(path);
}
```

My current approach is to use `Directory.GetFiles` to create a list of files which are in my path, then use `Parallel.ForEach` to convert the files. Here's my code:

```
string[] filesList = Directory.GetFiles(path);
Parallel.ForEach(filesList, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20 }, file =>
{
    if (file.Contains(".doc"))
    {
        ConvertDocToDocx(file);
    }
});
```

However, this doesn't seem to increase performance. Am I misunderstanding the use of `Parallel.ForEach`?

Comment: If you've got _millions_ of files to process, you might want a more robust queuing system than doing everything on a single computer.

Comment: For IO operations use Task, not Parallel, not Thread, but Task.

Comment: As a side note, you could include a search pattern as an argument in the `GetFiles` method: `string[] filesList = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.doc");`. Regarding the main issue, could you reduce the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to `2`, and see if it makes any difference?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias he uses Microsoft Word Object Library which is COM library (hence IO mostly), he can just use tasks for this, which comes with in-memory queue already.

Comment: @eocron why? Where is it documented that you can't create two COM objects from two different threads, and invoke them in parallel?

Comment: I didn't say you can't, I just said that its meaningless. Tasks will complete in dynamic manner, without specifying degree.

Comment: @eocron what will happen if you start two independent processes in parallel, where each process converts a different doc file to docx? Is it going to be as fast as converting both doc files sequentially from a single process?

Comment: Tasks processed in thread pool, in a manner they see fit. It can (and most of the time will) be parrallel if it has resources, all the other time it will just wait for COM library to respond.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Word via automation which is equivalent of opening the files manually one by one and saving them. This method may have one performance increasing possibility: there is no need to create new Word instances for each file, just reuse the first instance.

```cs
...
var wordInstance = new Application();
try
{
   var fileNameList = Directory.GetFiles(path);
   foreach(var fileName in fileNameList)
   {
      if (fileName.Contains(".doc"))
      {
         ConvertDocToDocx(wordInstance, file);
      }
   }
}
finally
{
   word.Quit();
}
...

static void ConvertDocToDocx(Application wordInstance, string path)
{
   var sourceFile = new FileInfo(path);
   var newFileName = sourceFile.FullName.Replace(".doc", ".docx");

   var document = wordInstance.Documents.Open(sourceFile.FullName);
   document.SaveAs2(
      newFileName, 
      WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument,
      CompatibilityMode: WdCompatibilityMode.wdWord2010);

   wordInstance.ActiveDocument.Close();
   //File.Delete(path);
}
```

But as others already mentioned that is the limit of this approach.
You should have a look at solutions which are based on file format knowledge, like e.g. NPOI. It is a C# rewrite of popular Apache POI package so if you search for "POI convert doc to docx" and find Java code do not be afraid almost the same code will compile under C# with NPOI package too, in most cases just minor syntax changes would be required.